# How can I view the key-exchange protocol in Firefox

Tags: firefox, ssl

I set `Firefox` to use certain type of `ciphersuites` through `config:about`. For example, only ciphersuites with `DHE` key-exchange. Now, I connected to an SSL web server. I need to know which `ciphersuite` exactly used, in particular, I want to make sure that `Firefox` negotiated `DHE` key-exchange. How can I find this piece of information ? I can find this information using `Chrome`, but I do not know how to configure `Chrome`.

Answer (score 1):

If you click the padlock on the https page that you have open when you click on "More information", the technical details at the bottom will say which Cipher Suite Firefox is using to establish the connection. 
You could also use a add-on called CipherFox https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/cipherfox/?src=search

Good luck!